# Почему в данном предложении нет запятой перед союзом И?

Tags: запятые, сложное-предложение, ссп, и

***Он уже хотел вернуться и даже попытался остановить лифт, но скользнул взглядом по тексту и палец его замер, так и не коснувшись кнопки «стоп».***

Это ССП, первое предложение осложнено однородными сказуемыми, а второе – деепричастным оборотом.

Можно ли по правилам объяснить отсутствие запятой перед вторым союзом И?

Спасибо.

**А где же ответы?!**

**Проблемы такие.**

1. Розенталь не считает союз НО общим элементом в ССП.
2. Почему – неизвестно, про другие союзы он вообще  ничего не говорит.
3. Союз И стоит не между предложениями, а между третьим сказуемым первого предложения и вторым предложением. По интонации между ними паузы действительно нет.
4. **А по правилам как всё это объяснить?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Имхо, знак нужен. Это может быть тире или отточие. Причём после соединительного *и*. Ничегошеньки не соединяющего.

*Он хотел вернуться, попытался остановить.* Всё с первым предложением.

*Палец замер.* Всё со вторым.

И неважно, чем там оба осложнены.

---

Как варьянт:

*Он уже хотел вернуться и даже попытался остановить лифт, но скользнул взглядом по тексту и... палец его замер, так и не коснувшись кнопки «стоп».*

Answer (score 5):

Прекрасно! Вчера у меня не было ни одного ответа, а теперь целых три, включая мой собственный.

**Вариант 1.** Начну с ответа Надежды. Она предлагает не ставить запятую перед союзом И, так как «знаки должна разделять мысли».  То есть речь идет о постановке только одной  запятой перед союзом НО,  и тогда предложение делится **на два смысловых блока,** что вполне справедливо.

При этом она  для примера составляет похожее по смыслу предложение, оставляя только **однородные сказуемые:** *Он уже хотел вернуться и даже попытался остановить лифт, // но скользнул взглядом по тексту и замер, так и не коснувшись кнопки «стоп».* (Как известно, однородные сказуемые мы можем комбинировать в том порядке,  который нужен автору для выражения заданного смысла.)

**Вариант 2.** Я тоже думала над этим предложение, но при этом вспомнила тему, о которой редко говорится в правилах – **«Контаминированные типы сложных синтаксических конструкций»** (из учебника Валгиной для вузов «Современный русский язык» 2003 года).  В этой теме при построении сложных предложений в качестве элементов используется **не простые структуры, а сложные**.

В нашем случае в позиции третьего однородного сказуемого после союза НО находится сложносочиненное предложение: *Он уже хотел вернуться и даже попытался остановить лифт, но **(скользнул взглядом по тексту и палец его замер, так и не коснувшись кнопки «стоп»**).* Соответственно, отсутствие запятой перед союзом И говорит нам о том, что  здесь ССП – **это единая конструкция.**

**Вариант 3.** Но вот Галина предлагает нам **другое  смысловое деление,** которое мне кажется очень оригинальным  и, пожалуй,  более художественным: *Он уже хотел вернуться и даже попытался остановить лифт, но скользнул взглядом по тексту и... **палец его замер, так и не коснувшись кнопки «стоп».***

**Смысловая пауза** делается в другом месте и обозначается тире или отточием. Здесь более точно и выразительно обозначен **поворот (фактически потрясение)**  в сознании нашего героя. Ситуация в романе такая.

*Студент биофака МГУ  – очень обаятельный молодой человек – никак не может исключить из своей жизни темную магию, с который оказался  связанным в силу своего рождения.   Вот и теперь он привозил старичку-профессору для утверждения тему курсового. Тот был несколько удивлен темой, но все-таки подписал, да вот только не то, что нужно. В рюкзаке у студента оказался «Список артефактного магического оружия», неизвестно откуда взявшийся.*

Вот такие **художественные возможности дает русская пунктуация,** даже заключенная в жесткие рамки правил (что тоже необходимо). Но чтобы пользоваться этими возможностями, надо **любить и чувствовать язык, а не просто выучить эти правила.**

Я  очень благодарна тем, кто действительно помог  мне решить непростую задачу, хотя вопрос  довольного долго не вызывал интереса. Я **приму ответ Галины** (мне ее решение кажется более интересным с точки зрения психологии), но при этом прошу общество оценить  ответ и интересные мысли в комментариях нашего **нового участника**.

Comment: У ти мой холёсий! Я - да, такой - психологический весь...

Comment: И - не вопрос "долго не вызывал интереса", у него - глянь, нет-нет, ты - глянь скока многа просмотров. А - а с какого боку подступиться то?! О_о И я к нему возвращалась - удалялась не солоно - возвернулася, осмелев. Дерзкая мы.

Answer (score 3):

Я так отвечу. Не знаю, какой знак там может стоять, но точно не запятая. Даже если нет такого правила про запятую, то его следовало бы выдумать.

С запятой нарушается не только структура текста, но и смысл искажается.

Что мы имеем при наличии запятой? Сложносочиненное предложение, первая часть которого осложнена рядом однородных сказуемых.

*Он... хотел вернуться... и... попытался, но скользнул... , и палец его замер.*

Совершенно непонятно, к чему тут логически пришита вторая часть. Замечу, кстати, что все разговоры про общий член "но" просто лишены смысла, "но" не соединяет два предложения, а лишь вводит элемент в ряд однородных сказуемых.

Теперь как это трактовать без запятой.

*Он... хотел вернуться... и... попытался, (1) но скользнул... , и палец его замер.*

Тоже СС, но совсем другой структуры. На цифре (1) первая часть сложносочиненного предложения кончается – и начинается вторая часть, в свою очередь состоящая из двух ССП – "хотел" (определенно-личное, неполное с опущенным подлежащим "он") и "палец... замер" (определенно-личное, полное, двусоставное).

Так вот "но" в данном случае вводит два предложения, занимающих структурно один уровень, то есть однородных. Вот эта-то однородность и позволяет обойтись без запятой.

Общим же членом для двух предложений является... первая часть ССП, то есть *"он хотел... и попытался"*.
Подобных примеров у Розенталя нет. Ссылаться на него в части, что он возражает против отсутствия запятой в подобных случаях, просто некорректно.

Зато есть недвусмысленная формулировка:

> 2. Перед союзами ***и, да*** (в значении и), ***или, либо*** запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения объединены каким-либо общим элементом.

Подчеркиваю – у Р. – **каким-либо**. Никаких ограничений или оговорок на это "либо" Розенталь не приводит.

Другой вопрос, что там может стоять вместо запятой... Боюсь, что ничего хорошего там поставить нельзя. По тем же причинам. Любой знак (тире, точка с запятой, многоточие) сломает структуру предложения, разделив его совсем не на те части, которые подразумеваются автором.

Касательно того, что "скользнул" надо/можно трактовать не как однородное сказуемое, а как самостоятельное предложение.
Совсем недавно мне дали ссылку (не Вы ли, Sharon?) на то, что Валгина, пусть и с оговоркой, допускает подобный подход (что впрочем для меня совершенно не было новостью). Искать сейчас просто не имею возможности, но если вопрос станет ребром – найду попозже.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы так решила, что союз "но" относится не только к "скользнул взглядом по тексту", но и к "палец его замер" (причем к этой части даже в большей степени) - поэтому запятая не нужна.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение, прекрасно, что вы не только задаете вопросы, но и отвечаете. По смыслу и по интонации это верно, но как объяснить  грамматику и пунктуацию по правилам.
Формально союз И соединяет два предложения, а общего элемента у них нет. У Розенталя это выглядит так: 2. Перед союзами и, да (в значении и), или, либо запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения объединены каким-либо общим элементом http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133 Союз НО по Розенталю общим элементом не является.

Comment: К сожалению, я не настолько хорошо знаю правила, поэтому могу только порассуждать. Может быть, все же союз "но" тоже соединяет эти два предложения, потому что там явно есть отношения противопоставления.

Comment: Интересно то, что он соединяет однородное сказуемое и предложение. Тогда нужно считать однородное сказуемое неполным предложением с пропущенным подлежащим "он". Да только общего элемента у них них все равно формально нет. А нам нужна ссылка на определенное правило. Что делать? Вот вы, к примеру, автор и не хотите там ставить запятую, а редактор требует поставить, так как отсутствие запятой надо объяснять правилами. Ваши действия?

Comment: Случись такое, я бы сказала, что запятая должна разделять мысли. Что если бы вместо "палец замер" было просто "замер", про взгляд я бы вообще запросто переделала в деепричастный оборот - и тогда стало бы видно, что это добавочная информация и союз "но" относится не к ней, а к "замер". И если мы поставим запятую перед "и", то разделим мысль "но замер", причем завершим первое простое предложение на весьма странной ноте, у нас получится нелогичное высказывание, это будет плохо звучать и неудобно читать: Он уже хотел вернуться и даже попытался остановить лифт, но скользнул взглядом по тексту.

Comment: @Sharon сколько ни читаю по вашей ссылке, не вижу у Розенталя таких слов, что "но" не является-де общим элементом. Можето процитировать хотя бы начало предложение, которое позволило Вам утрерждать подобное?

Comment: @Nadezhda может Вы и не знаете правил (как утверждаете), но что вы совершенно верно чувствуете их дух - безусловно. Конечно, ваша формулировка оставляет желать лучшего... Но по сути все правильно. Я чуть позже дам свой ответ, думаю, вы его поймете.

Comment: @behemothus   http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133   Пункт 2. 1) Общим может быть второстепенный член предложения: Примечание 2. Противительный союз, после которого или перед которым находятся два соединенных союзом и простых предложения, общим элементом не является, поэтому запятая перед и ставится:Ибрагим был бы очень рад избавиться, НО ассамблея была дело должностное, и государь строго требовал присутствия своих приближённых (П.);

Comment: @Sharon - A... да, пропустил, не придал значения этому примичанию, но это, полагаю, все равно не о том... Навскидку там совсем другая структура в примерах, три как бы однородных предложения и действительно нет общей смысловой части помимо этого "но".. Посмотрю внимательнее, сейчас просто не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Это уникальный случай. У него не было шансов попасть в правила.

Дело в том, что НО здесь относится к "*палец его замер*", а "*скользнул взглядом по тексту*" выступает лишь предысторией. Без последней части противопоставления нет:
*Он уже хотел вернуться и даже попытался остановить лифт, но скользнул взглядом по тексту.* || Без продолжения НО как бы и не нужно (союз И подходит).
Это довольно сложный момент, не факт, что автор руководствовался этим, мог просто руководствоваться отсутствием паузы.

> Розенталь не считает союз НО общим элементом в ССП. Почему – неизвестно

В русском языке сложилось так, что противительные союзы тесно примыкают к одной фразе (к простому предложению), а дальше идёт следствие. Чтоб НО мог быть общим, необходимо, чтоб не было ни малейшего следствия, а для этого необходимы бытийные предложения. Но тогда союз И оказывается не кстати и требуется союз А:
*Мне нужен блокнот и ручка. Но ручка на столе и блокнот на холодильнике.* || Требуется союз А.
Разве что можно сделать такой обход:
*Мне нужен блокнот и ручка. Но ручка на столе и блокнот там же.* || Вот тут уже запятая вообще не к месту.
Подобные конструкции малоудачны и крайне маловероятны. Так что не зря Розенталь это всё запретил.

Comment: Это тот крутой вопрос, о котором говорил.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!  Так это у нас уникальный случай для союза НО?  :) А хотите, я составлю очень много таких  «уникальных» предложений по одной и той же схеме. Например: Я хотел отказаться, но прочитал письмо и сомнения вновь охватили меня.  Будем ставить запятую?

Comment: Когда вы знаете схему, то не проблема составить много подобных предложений (это как штамповать на заводе очень сложные механизмы, просто зная много производственных секретов), но "в природе" они попадаются редко. Уникальный случай — не значит единственный.

Comment: Вероятно,  это не единственная схема. А если даже так,  то зачем же Розенталю ее запрещать? Допустим, схема одна, а частотность ее применения высокая. Все будут неправильно писать?

Comment: Просто он мог с таким не сталкиваться. *Допустим, схема одна, а частотность ее применения высокая* — большинство будет стараться писать по правилам, чтоб ни у кого не возникало вопросов о корректности.

Comment: Автор пишет не для того, «чтоб ни у кого не возникало вопросов о корректности».  Для него важен художественный образ, а вы будете его править по Розенталю. И по поводу ШТАМПОВАНИЯ по схемам. Наша обычная речь именно так и выглядит – мы пользуемся готовыми грамматическими конструкциями, сами ничего не изобретаем.

Comment: Не только. Экспериментировать тоже интересно, да и полезно. *а вы будете его править по Розенталю* — лично я против запятой по причине, изложенной в ответе.